# Build error building an example Flex mxml

Tags: flash, flex3, adobe, apache-flex

I'm using the Flex 3.3 SDK (not Flex builder, as I'm on 64-bit Linux), and it seems I can't even build simple example files.
The Pie Chart example on http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_09.html refuses to build, giving me:

The generated actionScript is as follows:

```
package 
{
import flash.accessibility.*;
import flash.debugger.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.errors.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.external.*;
import flash.filters.*;
import flash.geom.*;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.printing.*;
import flash.profiler.*;
import flash.system.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.ui.*;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.xml.*;
import mx.binding.*;
import mx.charts.PieChart;
import mx.core.Application;
import mx.core.ClassFactory;
import mx.core.DeferredInstanceFromClass;
import mx.core.DeferredInstanceFromFunction;
import mx.core.IDeferredInstance;
import mx.core.IFactory;
import mx.core.IPropertyChangeNotifier;
import mx.core.mx_internal;
import mx.styles.*;
import mx.containers.Panel;
import mx.charts.Legend;
import mx.core.Application;
import mx.charts.series.PieSeries;

public class piechartTest extends mx.core.Application
{
    public function piechartTest() {}

    [Bindable]
    public var myChart : mx.charts.PieChart;

    mx_internal var _bindings : Array;
    mx_internal var _watchers : Array;
    mx_internal var _bindingsByDestination : Object;
    mx_internal var _bindingsBeginWithWord : Object;

include "/home/mathias/Stage/hadoop_testing/flex_test/piechartTest.mxml:4,15";

}}
```

I would absolutely love a simple solution to this problem, and I'm sure one exists, I just can't seem to find it (partially because every explanation seems to have been written for Flex Builder).

Answer (score 0):

Aha. The solution, apparently: http://pragmaticflex.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/charts-with-the-flex-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you have installed the datavisualization package to you 3.3 installation. The charts classes is in there and strangelly this package is separated of the rest of the sdk distribution.
google it to find  (but it is NOT listed on adobe confluence)

hope it helps